# show/hide div on click jquery not working

Tags: jquery, show-hide, slidetoggle

I want to show this Div when I click `My Account` link, i'm doing something wrong because is not working

This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VKvPX/1/ when i click my account nothing happens

```
<script>
    $("#showhide").on('click', function(){
        $(".more").children("div").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

credit go for this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56jdL/6/`

Comment: __ID must be unique__

Comment: + when you give a jsfiddle, don't forget to include library.

Comment: Best I can come up with [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKvPX/3/)

Comment: Thank you guys, @codel96 Honestly Im very know and I was not checking on that thank you for pointing it out for me

Answer (score 1):

It is not working becuase the `div` with class `more` has `display:none` on it, but your code tries to toggle the children of that element..

If you remove the `.children('div')` part it will work..

But it will not work for the logout link since it uses the same `id` which should be unique.

If you change that to a class as well then it will work for both links

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zjx7V/

**js**

```
$(".showhide").on('click', function(){
    $(".more").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

and for the links use

```
<a href="#" class="showhide">
```